# Extracting specific fields from mongodb

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I want to retrieve the the place names in my table **places** in the database **placedb**. 
my data in the database is in the following format

```
 **{ "_id" : ObjectId("514c23udhgfhdfge"), "placeList" : "chennai,coimbatore,madurai........", "state" : "tamilnadu" }**
```

below is the code which i had tried but it does not shows any output and i have no idea what went wrong

```
     MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017); //with default server and port adress


     DB db = client.getDB("placedb");

     DBCollection areaColl=db.getCollection("places");

     DBCursor find=areaColl.find();

     String places = "";
     while(find.hasNext())
     {
         places=find.next().get("placeList").toString();                
     } 
     System.out.println(places);
     String[] place=places.split(",");
     for(int i=0;i<place.length;i++)
     {
         System.out.println(place[i]);
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chk this............................................

```
     MongoURI uri = new MongoURI("mongodb://ip of server");
    Mongo mongo = (new Mongo.Holder()).connect(uri);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("placeDB");
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("places");
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
    JSONArray placeList = new JSONArray();
    String places = "";
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        places = cursor.next().get("placeList").toString();

    }
    String[] place = places.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < place.length; i++) {
        placeList.add(place[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(placeList);
```

Comment: thanks Rose but i need some specific field not the entire o/p

Answer (score 2):

This is how your code should look like:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017); //with default server and port adress


     DB db = client.getDB("placedb");

     DBCollection areaColl=db.getCollection("places");


     BasicDBObject allQuery = new BasicDBObject();
     BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
     fields.put("placeList", 1);
     DBCursor cursor = areaColl.find(allQuery, fields);

     String places = "";
     while(cursor.hasNext())
     {
         places=cursor.next().toString(); 
         System.out.println(places);               
     } 

     String[] place=places.split(",");
     for(int i=0;i<place.length;i++)
     {
         System.out.println(place[i]);
     }
```

Comment: is your db password protected?

Comment: it was made by some one else...i have to access their db...i don't think it will be a problem..... i think i have to specify only the i/p...i'm very new to mongodb

Comment: Check if you have specified the correct port, default port is 27017. If DB is password protected then you need to key in the user credentials as well.

Comment: sry vmr now it's working well...but i need only the "placelist" values it's giving entire o/p including "objectid"